# javascript countdown timer restart after every 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Hi i got the countdown timer code from :

https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq,

and have modified as :

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {


var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);

  return {
    'total': t,

    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);

  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }

    if(t.minutes == 0 && t.seconds ==0) {
        console.log('in this func');
        deadline = new Date(deadline.getTime() + 10*60000);
    }

  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

deadline = new Date(Date.parse('Fri Mar 30 2018 17:03:00 GMT+0530'));
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

what change, i have done is, i have checked if minutes and seconds both are 0, then the variable 'deadline' should be updated with new time. The countdown timer works fine but as it hits 0:0, it enters the function and everything stops.

Comment: `clearInterval(timeinterval);` will stop the interval (execution of the `updateClock` function once every second). Just remove that statement and the interval won't stop. Also, you should reset `endtime` instead of `deadline`

Comment: Well that is how it is coded..... `if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize clock again when it hits `0:0` ([updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvvYYV))

```
if (t.minutes == 0 && t.seconds == 0) {
    console.log('in this func');
    deadline = new Date(deadline.getTime() + 10 * 60000);
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline); //added this line
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }

    if (t.minutes == 0 && t.seconds == 0) {
      console.log('in this func');
      deadline = new Date(deadline.getTime() + 10 * 60000);
      initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline); //added this line
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 1 * 1 * 1 * 6 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1 {
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #00BF96;
  display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div>span {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #00816A;
  display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried using this and all I get is "Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null "